# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Nativescript

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, nativescript

I'm using this plugin `tns plugin add nativescript-google-maps-sdk` for create a map. I follow step by step this [site](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk)

When run with `tns run`, in terminal show this error, like in photo.

Can you ask me any idea, why it's this error?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: did u include the api key as described there in documentation ?

Comment: `<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"          android:value="@string/my-map-209015" />` for this key?